# Add font to NSMutableAttributedString where .font attribute is missing

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, nsrange

I want to apply a specific font to an `NSMutableAttributedString` where no `.font` attribute is applied. How could I achieve that?
I tried enumerating the attributes that contain a font and extracting the ranges but I am kind of lost to the complexity of finding the ranges that don't contain a font attribute since I think I must handle intersections or possible unknown scenarios. Is there a simple way to do it?
What I did until now:

```
        var allRangesWithFont = [NSRange]()
        let stringRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: length)
        
        beginEditing()
        enumerateAttribute(.font,
                           in: stringRange,
                           options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { (value, range, stop) in
            
            if let f = value as? UIFont {
                allRangesWithFont.append(range)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your way of thinking, instead, check if the font is not there, and apply your new font directly.

With `attrStr` being your `NSMutableAttributedString`, and `newFont` the font you want to apply.

```
let newFont = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
attrStr.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length), options: []) { value, subrange, pointeeStop in
    guard value == nil else { return }
    attrStr.addAttribute(.font, value: newFont, range: subrange)
}
```

Comment: That was so obvious, I went on the presumption that `enumerateAttribute ` only returned ranges where the font was found, thanks! The `if let f = value as? UIFont` check was for `CTFont` and other possible font classes but I did not expect it to return the range if no font was set and I did not even check, my bad.

Comment: You are enumerating on `NSAttributedStringKey.font`, so value will be a `UIFont?`. If you enumerate all attributes, then, indeed you need to check `as? UIFont`.